# Edge detection of a ppm object

Tags: c++

I am kind of in desperation mode trying to figure out what is missing. I have an assignment for school that is asking use to do edge detection. I am a novice in c++ and programming general. I have a problem with vertical detection and have code that looks like this.

```
void verticalDetection(std::string in_file, std::string out_file) {
    PPM verticals;
    std::ifstream input_file(in_file);
    std::ofstream output_file(out_file);
    input_file >> verticals;

    int i, j, k, new_c1, new_c2;
    int check = verticals.getMaxColorValue() / 10;
    for (i = 0; i < verticals.getHeight() ; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < verticals.getWidth() ; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < 3 ; k++) {

                if (k==0) {
                    double r1 = verticals.getChannel(i, j, k);
                    double g1 = verticals.getChannel(i, j, k+1);
                    double b1 = verticals.getChannel(i, j, k+2);

                    double r2 = verticals.getChannel(i, j-1, k);
                    double g2 = verticals.getChannel(i, j-1, k+1);
                    double b2 = verticals.getChannel(i, j-1, k+2);
                    double c1 = 0.2126*r1 + 0.7152*g1 + 0.0722*b1;
                    double c2 = 0.2126*r2 + 0.7152*g2 + 0.0722*b2;
                    new_c1 = (int)c1;
                    new_c2 = (int)c2;

                    if ((new_c1 - new_c2 > 0 && new_c1 - new_c2 <= check) || (new_c2 - new_c1 > 0 && new_c2 - new_c1 <= check)) {
                    verticals.setChannel(i, j, k, 255);
                    verticals.setChannel(i, j, k+1, 255);
                    verticals.setChannel(i, j, k+2, 255);
                    } else {
                    verticals.setChannel(i, j, k, 0);
                    verticals.setChannel(i, j, k+1, 0);
                    verticals.setChannel(i, j, k+2, 0);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    output_file << verticals;
}
```

though the output has some resemblance of being right it looks nothing like the example provided. The assignment asks this.

> Find a vertical edge by comparing every pixel’s brightness to the pixel at its left. If the pixel’s brightness differs by at least 10% of the max color value, then there is an edge detected at this pixel. Pixels must be set to white where an edge has been detected and black where an edge has not been detected.
>
> For the purposes of this assignment, brightness is defined as the linear colorimetric value of a pixel.

What am I doing incorrectly? I feel my thinking is flawed here. I'll provide an image of my output vs the expected correct output.

[image: my output]

Expected:
[image: expected output]

Comment: `for (k = 0; k < 3 ; k++)` What is the point of this loop?

Comment: The ppm object stores each channel of a ppm file r, g b, in a vector of unsigned chars. it is to index into each channel separately but when looking at the pixel as a whole, I only care about when we are at the first index of the pixel, or the red value.

Comment: I suppose it is possible to do some form of stepping by 3 for this particular function, but that is currently not where I believe the issue is.

Comment: I don't understand the words you wrote but "*I only care about when we are at the first index*" means you can replace the loop by `k = 0;` because any other `k` value is ignored anyway.

Comment: i = column, j = row, k = channel of the pixel

Comment: You can keep repeating yourself or you can look at the code, which ignores your "channel" and always has `k = 0` in the loop body.

Comment: Your `j` logic is a bit weird. Every iteration of the inner loop sets the pixel at `(i, j)` (to black or white), then increments `j`, then inspects the pixel at `(i, j-1)` (which was reset in the previous iteration). I think you're detecting edges between the original image and the unfinished results of edge detection (instead of looking at the original image only).

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to do it *"in place"*. You need to allocate/new[] an output image at the start and write your zeroes and 255s in there without overwriting your input image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Nah, switching `j` to top-down iteration (i.e. reversing the order of iteration) would suffice.

Comment: Your `if` statement is a bit clumsy, think about `if(abs(new_c1-new_c2))>check)`